# How do you calculate ETF yield when accounting for expense ratio?

Tags: etf, yield

I am not sure how to wrap my head around how to calculate the real yield of an ETF using it's **distribution yield** and **gross expense ratio**.

What I really want to know is, given both **ETF A** and **ETF B** are the same price and perform the same, which is better?

- **ETF A**: Yield `4.60%`, Gross Expense Ratio `0.12%`
- **ETF B**: Yield `4.56%`, Gross Expense Ratio `0.10%`

Is it simple subtraction?

Comment: Yields are usually net of fees but what metric are you using to determine better? A has better yield after fees and before fees but is that all you want or does the capital appreciation of shares factor into things here at all?

Comment: I'm just trying to calculate yield after fees honestly. I guess to make it harder we can add a bunch of different factors, price, appreciation... etc.

Comment: If you are taking the dividends from the ETF in cash then this can be useful. However if you re-investing them then a different calculation may be worth doing to see what the total return is on the funds. That's the reason why I asked the questions in the comment.

Comment: I see what you mean. Not as simple as I though. TBH I will be re-investing them.